# How do I find the elements in an ng-repeat that is populated by an ajax call

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to use Protractor for some end-2-end testing and I am running into a problem below:

I have this html:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    ....
    <tr ng-repeat="row in service.data">
        <td>
            {{row.name}}
        </td>                               
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-modal="row.checked"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

and in my angular, I have the following js:

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
    $http.get('/api/service/').success(function(res){
       $scope.service.data = res.data;
    });
});
```

I am having trouble finding the table rows that are generated from the `ng-repeat` because they aren't there when the page loads.

My test is using this code:

```
var items = element.all(by.repeater('row in service.data')).then(function(row){
    // But row is always []. It doesnt wait for $http to finish
});
```

I am trying to make a test case to check the checkbox and click another action button, but I need Protractor to wait for the $http call to finish and angular renders the `ng-repeat` first.

Comment: What makes these rows appear in the page?

Comment: the ng-repeat that repeats 'service.data' that gets set by an angular $http call

Comment: But what triggers this $http call? You're saying that the data is not there when the page loads. So when does it appear? When the user clicks on a button?

Comment: its in a angular controller, so $http runs when the page loads

Comment: Then protractor should see them, unless the http call returns an empty array, or causes an error, or takes a big time to answer. Do you see them when executing the test? Where is the code?

Comment: The service call takes around 4-5 seconds to return data. Protractor stops the test before the service call is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem!

There were two problem that needed to be fix!

1.Make sure to defined the rootElement property in the conf.js if your angular app is not in the body!

```
exports.config = {
    ...
    rootElement : '.element' // css selector to the element that contains ng-app
}
```

2.I turned browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; in beforeEach and forgot to turn it back on for each test case.

```
beforeEach(function(){
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    ....
});

it('case', function(){
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    ....
});
```